# Android imagebutton change programmatically?

Tags: android, xml, drawable, imagebutton

Hello I have an imagebutton `linearButton` which has a background drawable set in the XML. I want to conditionally replace the background within the code, but it never happens!

```
Drawable replacer = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.replacementGraphic);
linearButton.setBackgroundDrawable(replacer);
```

This seems to be ineffective, is there a "reload" function for a imagebuttons that I have to call before they change visually?

Comment: What you do should work.  Show us some more code so that we can help you.

Comment: hey, thanks it was working, I meant to remove this question, but the added answer is helpful too!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `invalidate()` method will force a redraw of any view:

```
Drawable replacer = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.replacementGraphic);
linearButton.setBackgroundDrawable(replacer);
linearButton.invalidate();
```

See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate()) for reference.

Comment: Yup you want to invalidate the view to force Android to redraw it

Answer (score 4):

The "correct" answer should be updated.

`setBackgroundDrawable()` was deprecated in API 16

`setBackground()` was added in API 16

A better answer may be:

```
int replace = R.drawable.my_image;
myButton.setBackgroundResource(replace);
myButton.invalidate();
```

or just:

```
myButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_image);
myButton.invalidate();
```

**Will work from API level 1-18**

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
linearButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.replacementGraphic);
```

I hope it should work