# Imagebutton change programmatically?

Tags: android, imagebutton

I'm trying to change the image of the ImageButton programmatically.

I'm trying to copy this code, but the setBackgroundDrawable is already deprecated.

```
public void giveClue(View view) {
    Drawable replacer = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon2);
    ((ImageButton) view).setEnabled(false);
    ((ImageButton) view).setBackgroundDrawable(replacer);
    gameAdapter.giveClue(game);
}
```

My button was created using xml as follows:

```
   <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ImageButton2"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ImageButton3"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" 
        android:onClick="giveClue"/>
```

Comment: Duplicate of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751875/android-imagebutton-change-programmatically

Answer (score 158, accepted):

your code is trying to change the background of the button. not its image.
Those are two different things

```
  ((ImageButton) view).setImageResource(R.drawable.icon2);
```

Comment: It doesn't work, the xml always override what you changed to the previous state specified in xml attribute (app:srcCompat).

Answer (score 20):

Try this its working for me,Change the background image programmatically,

```
 image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ico);
```

Comment: You should use [setImageResource](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource(int)) instead.

Answer (score 4):

Hi you can use the following code

```
if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN ) 
{
    ((ImageButton) view).setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier("icon2", "drawable", getPackageName()));
}
else 
{
    ((ImageButton) view).setImageDrawable(getDrawable(getResources().getIdentifier("icon2", "drawable", getPackageName())));
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

In Kotlin you can use this code:

```
val myImageButton = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.myImageButton)  

myImageButton.setOnClickListener {

     (myImageButton as ImageButton).setImageResource(R.drawable.myIcon) 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try out this way:

> ((ImageButton) view).setImageDrawable(replacer);

Answer (score 0):

Using Kotlin, you can do this:

```
val myImageButton = ImageButton(context).apply({
    background = null
    setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, 
                         R.drawable.ic_save_black_24px))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

For kotlin this works for me

```
yourimagebuttonID.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_check_black_24dp)
```

Answer (score -4):

Try `((ImageButton) view).setImageDrawable(replacer);`